# Change the edge style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I want to make the attached tikzpicture.  First, how do I change the arrows to ankled arrows?  Second, how do I align a node below a node that's at the top to skip the one between them?

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [io] (a){technical device};
\node [below=of a] (does) {Does it move?};
\node [below right= of does] (si) {Should it?}; 
\node [below left = of does] (si2) {Should it?};
\node [below left = of si2] (wd40) {WD-40};
\node [below right = of si2] (ok) {OK};
\node [below right= of si] (dt) {duct tape};

\draw[->]
    (a) edge (does)
    (does) -- ++(2.9,0)
         |- (si.north)
    (does) edge (si2)
    (si2) edge (wd40)
    (si2) edge (ok);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

edit2:

```
\draw[->]
    (a) edge (does)
    (does) -- ++(2.9,0)
         -| (si.north)
    (does) edge (si2)
    (si2) -- ++(-1.5,0)
         -| (wd40.north)
    (si2) -- ++(1.5,0)
         -| (ok.north)
    (si) -- ++(2,0)
         -|(dt.north);
```

Now these paths are just lines why that?

Comment: If you add the code that produces the image you can produce, it will be easy. In `forest` you need to use `forked edges`, in Ti*k*Z you can change the `to path` or do other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use `tikz` and not forest to draw this decision tree, you could use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  decision/.style={diamond,draw, text width=4.5em, text badly centered,
    inner sep=1pt},
  io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
    minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, 
    draw=black,trapezium stretches=true},
  block/.style={minimum width=2cm,draw},
  forked/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  node distance=1cm and 2cm
    ]
\node [io] (a){technical device};
\node [below=of a,decision] (does) {Does it move?};
\node [below right= of does,decision] (si) {Should it?}; 
\node [below left = of does,decision] (si2) {Should it?};
\node [below left=1cm and 1cm of si2,block] (wd40) {WD-40};
\node [below right=1cm and 1cm of si,block] (dt) {duct tape};
\path (wd40) -- node [block] (ok) {OK} (dt);

\draw[-stealth,semithick]    (a) edge (does);
\draw[-stealth,semithick,forked,nodes={above,font=\sffamily}]
    (does) edge node {yes}(si.north)
    (does) edge  node {no} (si2)
    (si2) edge node {yes}  (wd40)
    (si2) edge node {no}  (ok.160)
    (si) edge node {yes}  (ok.20)
    (si) edge node {no}  (dt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I added a preamble and some styles. BTW, in case you get told that things become so much better with the `quotes` library: please take these statements with a grain of salt.

Comment: Well thanks mate. So node.("number")  starts always on the top?

Comment: @RackCloud No. These are angles. Roughly speaking, these are the positions where a ray emitted from the node centers under an angle <angle> hits the node boundary.